# acquireTokenSilentAsync: The signed in account does not match with the provided account

Tags: android, azure-ad-msal

I am using MSAL for Android and confused about this error:

```
The signed in account does not match with the provided account.
(Error code current_account_mismatch, from acquireTokenSilentAsync)
```

This is what I am doing:

1. Uninstall my own app, install it again
2. Login via `signIn()` method of MSAL
3. Call `acquireTokenSilentAsync()`:

   ```
        val parameters = AcquireTokenSilentParameters.Builder()
            .withScopes(scopes.toList())
            .withCallback(authenticationCallback)
            .build()

        _msalPublicClient.acquireTokenSilentAsync(parameters)
   ```

   This call leads to a call of the onError method of the authenticationCallback with

> ```
> com.microsoft.identity.client.exception.MsalClientException: The signed in account does not match with the provided account.
> ```

How can that be fixed? How can the provided account (whatever that is?) be different from the signed in account on a new app installation?

Comment: I have similar problem using the new methods for acquireTokenSilentAsync as you (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74975180/microsofts-java-implementation-of-msal-isingleaccountpublicclientapplication-acq)

I linked it here so we can join forces...

Comment: ...and here is something from github...
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1475
saying that we need to use the deprecated one for a while... ?

Comment: ...another one... https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1742

Comment: AFAIK the new methods contains tests to check if current account is viable in certain situations: take a look here at lines 641-680 https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/blob/release/5.0.0/msal/src/main/java/com/microsoft/identity/client/SingleAccountPublicClientApplication.java - this was v5.0.0, they seems to be similar for v4.1.2...

Comment: It seems that Microsoft hasn't published 4.1.1, 4.1.2 and 5.0.0 on maven yet.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.identity.client/msal

Answer (score 0):

Based on this information: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-android/issues/1742#issuecomment-1526079463

You may do a suspended call (when using kotlin), something like this:

```
    suspend fun generateAccessToken(accessScope: String = MICROSOFT_ACCESS_SCOPE_USER_READ):String?
    {
        /**
         * Generates accessToken
         * */

        var accessToken: String?=null
        try {
            microsoftAccountViewModel.apply {
                singleAccountAppMLD.value?.let { singleAccountApp->
                    withContext(Dispatchers.IO){


                        val iAuthenticationResult = singleAccountApp.acquireTokenSilent(
                            AcquireTokenSilentParameters(
                                AcquireTokenSilentParameters.Builder()
                                    .withScopes(arrayOf(accessScope).toMutableList())
                                    .fromAuthority(MICROSOFT_ACCESS_AUTHORITY)
                                    .forAccount(singleAccountApp.currentAccount.currentAccount)
                                    
                            )
                        )
                        
                        accessToken = iAuthenticationResult.accessToken
                        lastIAuthenticationResultMLD.postValue(iAuthenticationResult)
                        Log.i(TAG, "M678: generateAccessToken: accessToken = $accessToken")


                    }
                }?:let {
                    Log.e(TAG, "generateAccessToken: singleAccountMLD.value = null !!")
                    Message.error(applicationContext.getString(R.string.message_error_you_may_not_be_signed_in_sign_in_again))
                }
            }
        }catch (exception: Exception)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "generateAccessToken: acquireTokenSilent exception", exception)
            Message.error(exception.message?:applicationContext.getString(R.string.message_error_acquire_token_unknown_error))
        }

        return accessToken
    }
```