# Microsofts java implementation of MSAL ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication.acquireTokenSilent is deprecated, new method gives 401 unauthorized error

Tags: android, kotlin, azure-ad-msal, acquiretokensilent

MSALs java methods of `ISingleAccountPublicClientApplication`
`signIn(activity, loginHint, scopes, authenticationCallback)` and `acquireTokenSilent(scopes, authority)` is deprecated, in favour of build methods.

So I changed the `signIn` to use `SignInParameters.builder()` like this:

(below in kotlin)

From:

```
...signIn(
    signInActivity,
    null, //loginHint 
    arrayOf(accessScope),
    object : AuthenticationCallback { /*omitted*/ },
   )
```

To:

```
...signIn(
    SignInParameters.builder(
        .withActivity(signInActivity),
        .withScopes(arrayOf(accessScope).toMutableList())
        .withCallback(
            object : AuthenticationCallback { /*omitted*/ 
        })
        .build()
    )
```

So far, the sign in process seems to go well, no errors, but the problems occures when I call the new `acquireTokenSilent` method with `AcquireTokenSilentParameters` used.

From:

```
val iAuthenticationResult = singleAccountApp.acquireTokenSilent(
                                arrayOf(accessScope),
                                MICROSOFT_ACCESS_AUTHORITY
                        )
```

To:

```
val iAuthenticationResult = singleAccountApp.acquireTokenSilent(
                            AcquireTokenSilentParameters(
                                AcquireTokenSilentParameters.Builder()
                                    .withScopes(arrayOf(accessScope).toMutableList())
                                    .fromAuthority(MICROSOFT_ACCESS_AUTHORITY)
                            )
                        )
```

Now I get following error message in response when acquiring token:
`The signed in account does not match the provided account` which further causes `401 Unauthorized` response.

Rewinding back to use the old method just for `acquireTokenSilent` does not produce any error and the token is provided.

Now I am stuck in new for `signIn` method, but an old one for the `acquireTokenSilent` method.

Is there anything I have skipped or forgotten using the newer one ?

Answer (score 1):

You should 'provide' the currentAccount of the logged in user.

```
val parameters = AcquireTokenSilentParameters.Builder()
            .withScopes(arrayOf(accessScope).toMutableList())
            .fromAuthority(MICROSOFT_ACCESS_AUTHORITY)
            .forAccount(singleAccountApp.currentAccount.currentAccount)
            .build()

val iAuthenticationResult = singleAccountApp.acquireTokenSilent(parameters)
```